# Iron-Router does not install

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've been following the Book "Discover Meteor" and in the Iron-Router part, they say to install

```
mrt add iron-router
```

and it says

```
Stand back while Meteorite does its thing
Done installing smart packages
Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!
=> Running Meteor from a checkout -- overrides project version (0.7.0.1)
iron-router: Routing specifically designed for Meteor
```

But when i run meteor... it says:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:
While building the application:
error: no such package: 'iron-router'
```

I've removed and try to install.. and then update mrt and meteor, it says:

```
Installing Meteor
branch: https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git#master
Installing smart packages
✓ iron-router
tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git#v0.6.1
Done installing smart packages
```

But when i run it still gives the same error, saying that there is no package iron-router.

any ideas? thanks

Comment: well google came up with this http://www.paypertise.com/meteorjs/iron-router-tutorial, a bit of configuration to do after the install.

Comment: are you running your project with 'mrt' or 'meteor'? it should be mrt.

Comment: It also seems that you are running meteor from a git checkout. Is that the case? If you run meteor from a release (i.e., using the install.sh script), there shouldn't be any problems with the way you added iron-router.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you execute `mrt add iron-router` under the root directory, not from within a subdirectory.

Comment: Now I know I can't just run mrt add in any old place I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can find the answer to this question here:
[meteor with mrt - iron:router: no such package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384231/meteor-with-mrt-ironrouter-no-such-package)

Installation of IronRouter for **meteor 0.8.3 and older**:

```
$ mrt add iron-router
```

Installation of IronRouter for **meteor 0.9.0 and newer**:

```
$ meteor add iron:router
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments.

I forgot to edit the smart.json with the code in the url http://www.paypertise.com/meteorjs/iron-router-tutorial
thanks for the tip Tony Hopkinson

Also coffeescript is not running very well in Meteor.