# meteor with mrt - iron:router: no such package

Tags: meteor, meteorite, iron-router

I'm learning `meteor 0.8.3` and trying to get some basic routing set up using [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router)

My `smart.json` contains:

```
{
  packages: {
    iron-router: {
      git: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git,
      branch: blaze-integration
    }
  }
}
```

I added this, and then ran `mrt install` and `mrt update`

Then I did this, and got this error:

```
$ meteor add iron:router
iron-router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
iron:router: no such package
```

I'm still able to run the application with `mrt`, and the application starts, but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined` from layout.js:92 and nothing shows up on the page.

My Router block looks like this:

```
 Router.map( function() {
   this.route('home', { path: '/' });
   this.route('create');
   this.route('tasksShow', { 
     path: '/tasks/:_id',
     data: function() { return Tasks.findOne(this.params._id); }
   });
 });
```

What am I doing wrong, how can I get iron-router working?

Comment: Clear iron-router entry from smart.json and install again using:
`mrt add iron-router`

Comment: Forgot to put that in the question body, but I did perform that step - and, to be safe, I tried again. I did `mrt add iron-router && mrt install && mrt update && meteor add iron:router` and still got `iron:router: no such package` as a final result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor update to 0.8.3 breaks app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383794/meteor-update-to-0-8-3-breaks-app)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Installation of IronRouter :

#### Meteor 0.8.3 and older

`$ mrt add iron-router`

#### Meteor 0.9.0 and newer

`$ meteor add iron:router`

More about this issue here: [Installation issues with iron-router (newest) on Windows 7 x64 (Meteor 0.8.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352582/installation-issues-with-iron-router-newest-on-windows-7-x64-meteor-0-8-3/25353164#25353164)

Comment: I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#installation -- it seems to specifically suggest that one should add the package with `mrt` **and** add the package with `meteor add`. Did I misread that, or is the documentation out of date?

Comment: The problem is caused by using meteor 0.8.3 and the instruction is prepared for meteor 0.9.0. Migrate to meteor 0.9.0 or try to install using `mrt add iron-router`.